# An "insert into" mySQL query through PHP appears to work, but nothing is added

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: I realized my problem was that I was trying to insert $user_id, which has a string with numbers" into column user_id, which is type int. I converted the string into an integer. I still didn't quite figure out errors though, but that's because of time constraints. I'll get back to it some other time.

I'm trying to build a website on top of the advanced version of the php login system provided at http://www.php-login.net. In the Registration class of the script, there's a function that adds a new user to the database, and that code works totally fine:

```
$query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime) VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now())');
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_activation_hash', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_registration_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->execute();

// id of new user
            $user_id = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId();

            if ($query_new_user_insert) {
                // send a verification email
                if ($this->sendVerificationEmail($user_id, $user_email, $user_activation_hash)) {
                    // when mail has been send successfully
                    $this->messages[] = $this->lang['Verification mail sent'];
                    $this->registration_successful = true;
                } else {
                    // delete this users account immediately, as we could not send a verification email
                    $query_delete_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id');
                    $query_delete_user->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query_delete_user->execute();

                    $this->errors[] = $this->lang['Verification mail error'];
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = $this->lang['Registration failed'];
            }
```

I tried copying that code for another part of my site using the following code:

```
public function addNewTag($postContent) {
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        $query_add_tag = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO tags (tag_name, tag_short_name, tag_id, color, user_id, creation_time) 
VALUES(:tag_name, :tag_short_name, :tag_id, :color, :user_id, :creation_time)');
        $query_add_tag->bindValue(':tag_name', $postContent['tag_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_add_tag->bindValue(':tag_short_name', $postContent['tag_short_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_add_tag->bindValue(':tag_id', rand(100000000000, 999999999999), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_add_tag->bindValue(':color', $postContent['color'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_add_tag->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_add_tag->bindValue(':creation_time', time(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_add_tag->execute();
        if ($query_add_tag) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function is called with $_POST as the variable for $postContent with the code

```
$content->addNewTag($_POST);
```

When I do so, the function returns true ("1"), but when I check my database content, nothing is added. What could be the issue here? I'm not that great with mySQL, so maybe it's an obvious error somewhere else in my script.

Comment: `$query_add_tag` is always a PDOStatement object. It won't become a falsy value on execution failure so you cannot test `if ($query_add_tag)`

Comment: Have a look at the [PDO error handling manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). Choose an error method, the default is silent failure, which may be what you're seeing.

Comment: what's the output if you do a var_dump of $this->databaseConnection at the start of the function?

Comment: The login script I'm using seems to do the same thing for the registration. Are they doing it wrong? Or am I missing something... I'll add the rest of their code to my original post. (I'm new here.)

Comment: @AYM Yeah, that's faulty code. The variable always contains the PDO statement object, which will always be a truthy value. If there was ever a reason that that original code would fail (like an improperly connected database or bad permissions) it would not operate as expected and always return true.

Comment: @scrowler: It returns as "bool(true) 1bool(true)"

Comment: @scowler: Actually it just returns as "bool(true)".

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in `autocommit=0`? If so, please set `autocommit=1` or add commit at the end of your function. Should be something like:

```
$query_add_tag->commit();
```